# Is it possible to write type-generic entities in VHDL?

Tags: generics, vhdl, type-parameter

So, I recently inherited some VHDL code, and my first reaction was, "VHDL has structs, why do they use bit-vectors everywhere?" And then I realized this is because there does not seem to be any way to write anything like this:

```
entity Queue is
    generic (
        EL : type
    );
    port (
        data_in  : EL;
        data_out : EL;
        ...
    );
end entity Queue;
```

I really wish this were possible. Is there anything even remotely approximating it? Even if I have to retype the entity or component declarations, just some way to avoid retyping the architecture definition for every (modulo a generic width) type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, and implementing a Queue is one of the classic reasons to do it!

This has been in VHDL since VHDL-2008.  Tool support is variable as of mid-2012.  Talk about a slow-moving industry!

- Aldec [supports it completely](http://www.aldec.com/en/solutions/fpga_design/simulation_debugging).
- Modelsim has partial support - can't find a public link to their capabilities.  If you have it installed, it's in /technotes/vhdl2008.note
- Xilinx (XST/ISIM) doesn't support it, or even VHDL-2002.  I can't find a simple link, but [these](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx14_1/xst_v6s6.pdf) [PDFs](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx14_1/plugin_ism.pdf) have sections on VHDL compatibility, which only talk of VHDL-1993.
- Altera's tools [have partial support, but not for type generics](http://quartushelp.altera.com/11.1/mergedProjects/hdl/vhdl/vhdl_list_2008_vhdl_support.htm)

Comment: I'm not sure you're correct about Xilinx — I use 2002 constructs in my code and it simulates and synthesises fine (with XST and ISIM). Also, ISE allows for a VHDL compatibility setting of "200X". Their official docs on standard support may well be out-of-date though.

Comment: @detly: thanks for the update, it's been a while since I bothered attempting anything "this-century" with ISIM.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no...

Generic types are a new feature of the upcoming VHDL-2008 standard : http://www.doulos.com/knowhow/vhdl_designers_guide/vhdl_2008/vhdl_200x_major/#GenericTypes

However the support of VHDL-2008 by EDA tools is still very limited. Even if your tools support it, using this feature would make your code non-portable.

Sticking to VHDL-2002, a solution would be to declare your interface types in a package and `mytypes`and use it everywhere needed with `use work.mytypes.all`.

Comment: "upcoming VHDL-2008 standard" - that makes me grin :)  One day it'll be described as the "current VHDL standard", one day!