# vhdl :: creating a type with a size parameter

Tags: generics, types, size, vhdl

I was wondering is there was a way to defined a type with a size parameter in VHDL. e.g.

```
type count_vector(size: Natural) is unsigned (size-1 downto 0);
```

and then later on do something like

```
variable int : count_vector(32) := (others => '0');
variable nibble : count_vector(4) := (others => '0');
```

Essentially, is there a way to defined an "array-like" type, or is that not allowed by syntax?

I am currently trying to use generics for re-usability, but I would like to be able to take maximal advantage of generic typing (ie: [Is it possible to write type-generic entities in VHDL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10890551/is-it-possible-to-write-type-generic-entities-in-vhdl) ).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Davids answer is what I think you mean; however I would like to add that while you can use n-dimensional arrays in VHDL, only the first one may be unconstrained, as in Davids subtype.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity foo is
     generic (
        constant INT_LEFT:    natural := 32;
        constant NIB_LEFT:    natural := 4
     );
     -- note entity declarative items are forward looking only
     -- a port declaration requires a type or subtype declared in a package
     -- you can also use a package for any constants

     -- a type or subtype can be declared as an entity declarative item here:
--     subtype int_size is unsigned(INT_LEFT downto 0);
--     subtype nib_size is unsigned(NIB_LEFT downto 0);
end entity;

architecture fum of foo is
    -- or as an architecture declarative item here:
    subtype int_size is unsigned(INT_LEFT downto 0);
    subtype nib_size is unsigned(NIB_LEFT downto 0);   

begin
USAGE:
    process 
        variable int:  int_size := (others => '0');
        variable nibble: nib_size := (others =>'0');
    begin
        int := int + 3;
        -- the function "+" is L: UNSIGNED, R: NATURAL
        --  int_size and nibble_size are subtypes of UNSIGNED
        Report integer'IMAGE(TO_INTEGER(int));
        -- ditto for TO_INTEGER
        nibble := nibble + 2;
        -- if int_size or nibble_size were types it would require
        -- operator functions for those types.
        Report integer'IMAGE(TO_INTEGER(nibble));
        wait;
    end process;

end architecture fum;
```

---

Added:

This is in response to BennyBarns assertion in a comment on the question: "I would like to add that while you can use n-dimensional arrays in VHDL, only the first one may be unconstrained".

Contrary to the assertion:

```
entity t1 is
end entity;

architecture foo of t1 is

    type typeI is array ( natural range <>, natural range <>) of integer;

begin
    process is
        variable sigI : typeI(0 to 1, 0 to 1);  -- 2D integer array
    begin
        sigI(0,0) := 1;
        sigI(0,1) := 2;
        sigI(1,0) := 3;
        sigI(1,1) := 4; 
        report "Initialized indiviually";
        report "sigI(0,0) = " & integer'IMAGE(sigI(0,0));
        report "sigI(0,1) = " & integer'IMAGE(sigI(0,1));
        report "sigI(1,0) = " & integer'IMAGE(sigI(1,0));
        report "sigI(1,1) = " & integer'IMAGE(sigI(1,1));
        sigI := ((11,12),(13,14));
        report "Initialized as an aggregate";
        report "sigI(0,0) = " & integer'IMAGE(sigI(0,0));
        report "sigI(0,1) = " & integer'IMAGE(sigI(0,1));
        report "sigI(1,0) = " & integer'IMAGE(sigI(1,0));
        report "sigI(1,1) = " & integer'IMAGE(sigI(1,1));
        wait;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

The statement is imprecise and relates in the example subtype declaration to the deferred range constraint in the type declaration of UNSIGNED in package numeric_std.  The subtype indication requires a constraint either supplied by the type mark or explicitly.  It's only valid for a subtype indication type mark that is an unconstrained type.

A subtype declaration of an unconstrained type must provide a constraint just as if you had added

```
signal A: unsigned;
```

as an architecture declarative item to fum of entity foo:

```
ghdl -a foo.vhdl
foo.vhdl:24:12: declaration of signal "a" with unconstrained array type "unsigned" is not allowed
```

And just to make things interesting things interface lists can be special:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity fie is
    port (
        a:  in  unsigned
    );
end entity;

architecture fee of fie is

begin

EVAL:
    process (a)
    begin
        report "Fie:a range is " & integer'IMAGE(a'LEFT) & " to " & 
                                  integer'IMAGE(a'RIGHT) ;
    end process;

end architecture fee;

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity fie_tb is
end entity;

architecture fum of fie_tb is
    component fie is
        port (a: in unsigned);
    end component;

    signal aa:  unsigned (3 to 7);
begin

EUT: fie port map (a => aa);

end architecture;
```

The 'rules' can be found in the LRM section on **Index constraints and discrete ranges**, IEEE Std 1076-2008 5.3.2.2, -2002/-1993 3.2.1.1.

Comment: Nice, I see your answer address *the* question about "array-like" type with declaration of the subtype.  However, I wonder, what is the advantage of having a subtype declaration in the entity, instead of having it in the architecture ?

Comment: An Entity declarative item for a subtype based on generics or constants would be useful in this case if multiple architectures had the same size dependencies. An entity declarative part item is visible to  all the entity's architectures. It's still common to have models with two levels of abstraction (behavioral and structural) allowing separation of functional and timing verification. It's an orthogonal axis to design reuse enabled by subtypes declared in the architecture declarative part.