# Variable number of "in" ports in an entity?

Tags: simulation, vhdl

I am trying to simulate a destination control lift controller with `n` floors and `m` lifts. So from every floor, the user can enter a destination floor to go and gets a lift number in return. So to simulate this kind of lift controller, I need to have variable `in` ports (which would be equal to the number of floors), each of type integer. I tried searching on google but could not find anything useful. Can someone suggest me how we can do the above ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

In VHDL you can use unconstrained arrays as ports:

```
entity myDevice is
    port ( floors : in std_logic_vector;
           lifts  : in std_logic_vector 
    );
end entity myDevice;
```

The size of the port is the determined during elaboration by the size of the connected signal. If you need to know the size of the port in your architecture, you simply use the `'length`, `'range` or any other appropriate attribute:

```
architecture RTL of myDevice is
begin
pr_control : process(all) is
begin
    -- Code, code, code...

    for n in lifts'range loop
        process_lift(n);
    end loop;

    -- More code ...
end process pr_controll;
end architecture RTL;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always do something like this:

```
entity controller is generic (
    N : integer;
    M : integer
); port (
    Floors : in std_logic_vector(N-1 downto 0);
    Lifts  : in std_logic_vector(M-1 downto 0)
);
end controller;
```

You can find some more examples of this [here](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~jmoorkan/vhdlref/generics.html).

---

Or perhaps:

```
package foo is
    type integer_array is array (integer range <>) of integer;
end package;

entity controller is generic (
    N : integer;
    M : integer
); port (
    Floors : in foo.integer_array(N-1 downto 0);
    Lifts  : in foo.integer_array(M-1 downto 0)
);
end controller;
```

Comment: what if I want integer array instead of std_logic_vector i.e. each of the N and M values are not 0/1 but integers ?

Comment: Well, just like always, you'll need to create the integer vector in another package. But then it's just like before. See the edit.

Comment: I wrote program based on your suggestions as follows: `LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;
--USE ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
USE ieee.numeric_std.ALL;


package foo is
    type integer_array is array (integer range <>) of integer;
end package;

use foo.all;

entity controller is generic (
    N : integer;
    M : integer
); port (
    Floors : in foo.integer_array(N-1 downto 0);
    Lifts  : in foo.integer_array(M-1 downto 0)
);
end controller;` . But this give following error : `lift.vhdl:11:5: no declaration for "foo"
lift.vhdl:17:17: no declaration for "foo"
ghdl: compilation error`

Comment: Your use statement should be just `use foo`. You brought `integer_array` into scope, not `foo.integer_array`.

Comment: That should be use work.foo.all to clear up Aryabhatt's first error (11:5).  There should have been a second remaining error for the port interface signal declaration of Lifts as well as Floors. The remaining errors could be cleared up by prefixing foo (work.foo) in the port declarations for Floors and Lifts.  But that isn't necessary (e.g. instead Floors: in integer_array(N-1 downto 0);). The use clause making package foo visible with 'all' does that. Aryabhatt - you should make your interchange an Answer. (Oh, and a default for the generics unless you want default arrays integer ranged).

Comment: Also see my answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18236585/vhdl-creating-a-type-with-a-size-parameter "vhdl :: creating a type with a size parameter" where the type declaration for integer_array could be as an entity or architecture declarative item.  Strictly speaking Aryabhatt's answer isn't a variable number of "in" ports, it's using signal ports that are an array type.

Comment: Also for the type declaration of integer_type if used, I'd suggest an ascending range.  It'd be more natural to express elevator movement from the bottom upward.

Comment: Rather than integer_array, you might consider using VHDL-2008 type, integer_vector.  It is in the standard package, so nothing special is required to use it other than make sure the VHDL-2008 switch is on.  Not sure about the synthesis support for it though.

Comment: @JimLewis: It's comments like that, and trondd's answer that make me depressed that Xilinx still only supports VHDL-1987.

Comment: Re: VHDL08 type integer_vector. You could note Aryabhatt has indicated he's using ghdl which is VHDL93 compliant, with features from 2002 and 2008.